# asp.net Kendoui cannot access grid from code?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to access my grid from Javascript code but I have mistakes somewhere. Where?

**Here is my Grid code:**

```
 <div id="kendoo">
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<SalePortal.ServiceReference.Product>()
.Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(product => product.pID).Title("Product ID");
        columns.Bound(product => product.productName).Title("Product Name");
        columns.Bound(product => product.productPrice).Title("Price");
        columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Buy").Click("Sale"));
    })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .ServerOperation(false)
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetProduct","Home"))
    )

)
</div>
```

And here is my javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function Sale(e)
    {
        var grid = $("#kendoo").data("kendoGrid");
        var myvar = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
        alert(my.pID);


        var url = "@Url.Action("Sale", "Home")";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: { cID: 1, pID: prID },
        });
     }
</script>
```

The variable `grid` in javascript part shown as "undefined" when I run the website. Then It gives an error like :

```
"Javascript runtime error: dataItem of undefined or null reference"
```

I think because grid is undefined I get this error. How could I make this correct? I need to access selected row cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function Sale(e)
{
    var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid"); // Need to specify Grid Name/Id here
    var myvar = grid.dataItem($(this).closest("tr"));
    alert(my.pID);


    var url = "@Url.Action("Sale", "Home")";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { cID: 1, pID: prID },
    });
 }
</script>
```